# How do I get a vertical scroll bar on an XPages iNotes List View component?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

As the title says. I created an iNotes List view component in my XPage and it renders great.

The problem is that I have more fields then I can view on screen, and it does not appear to have a vertical scroll bar.

Is there a setting to switch that on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't appear to have a vertical scroll bar. I have created SPR SODY92NLB5 for development to investigate.